# PHP - Foreach SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to be able to paste a proxy list into a Text file and be able to update the rows status to 1 if the pasted proxy is in the Database. I got it kind of working im using explode to seperate the list and from there foreach it using a query function. The issue is it doesnt update. It works on the very last proxy only.

Query Function:

```
function Connect($host = false,$username = false,$password = false,$dbname = false) {

    //Try execute the PHP with no errors;
    try {

        //Create a PDO Session;
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        //Session Attributes;
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    }

    //Catch all PDOException errors;
    catch (PDOException $e) {

        //Make the PDO session false;
        $con = false;

    }

    //If no errors happened Make the PDO session true;
    return $con;

}

//Create a new function named query;
function query($sql = false,$dbname = false,$bind = false,$obj = false) {

    //Prepare The SQL Query;
    $query = Connect('localhost','xx','xx',$dbname)->prepare($sql);

    $res = true;

    //Execute Binded Query;
    try { $query->execute($bind); $res = true; }

    catch (PDOException $e) {

        $res = false;

    }

    //If no errors happened Make $row true;
    return $res;

}
```

And PHP:

```
<?php

//Define if Error Logging will be turned on (true) or off (false);
$errorlogging = true;
$obstart = false;
$adminonly = false;

//Set the default Timezone to UK/Ireland;
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//Globalized functionality needed on all pages;
require('common/requisites.php');

//Include The Database Connection;
require('common/db.php');

if(!empty($_POST['proxies'])) {

    $proxyinput = $_POST['proxies'];

    $proxies = explode("\n",$proxyinput);

    foreach($proxies as $proxy) {
        query('UPDATE proxies SET status = 1 WHERE :proxy = proxy','unfed_tools',array(':proxy'=>$proxy));
        echo "Updated: ".$proxy."\n\r";
    }

}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="proxies" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `WHERE proxy = :proxy`

Comment: @u_mulder No idea how I missed that but it's still only working on the last proxy.

Comment: Does the loop execute multiple times / do you get multiple "Updated: " messages?

Comment: @trincot Yes, It's looping getting updated messages.

Comment: Im not 100% certain but could this be to do with PDO-::prepare?

Comment: Could you also echo the return values of your calls to the query function?

Comment: @trincot What exactly do you mean?

Comment: It might also be an issue with the explode string. Im not full sure if thats the correct one to be using. Im copying the list from Notepad++ so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the line endings aren't `\r\n`? You might need to do `explode("\r\n",$proxyinput);` That would explain why it only works for the last proxy.

For example:
Example proxy file

```
proxy1\r\n
proxy2\r\n
proxy3\r\n
proxy4
```

Your explode gives you:

```
array("proxy1\r","proxy2\r","proxy3\r","proxy4")
```

So your search will only find the `proxy4`

**Edit:**

To account for users being annoying, you can:

```
explode("\n",str_replace("\r\n","\n",$proxyinput));
```

You shouldn't have to worry about the line endings ever being \n\r... AFAIK.

I noticed you commented that you are using Notepad++. You can use it to "Show All Characters"
[image]

Comment: Yes thats what I was thinking the only issue is how can I know which one the user is inputting? I don't even know which one.

Comment: \r\n seems to be working fine. But what if someone inputs a list that is lets say just \n or \n\r?

Comment: @JohnButler \r\n is standard for Windows (i'll be corrected if that's a false statement, I hope). It means \carriageReturn\lineFeed btw. You might run into a file with just the \n but i don't think you'll ever see \n\r unless someone is directly editing the file